# mvn -version not working

Tags: apache, maven

I downloaded apache-maven-3.2.5 on my system. For setting that up, I changed my environment variables as follows:

```
M2_HOME: C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.2.5
MAVEN_HOME: C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin
PATH: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;
```

On running mvn -version, it shows the error that :

```
'mvn' is not recognised as an external or internal command, operableprgram or batch file
```

I went across various other links on stackoverflow giving solution to the same problem. I tried many: restarting the system after making `MAVEN_HOME` AND `M2_HOME` as the system variables. Even I tried mentioning the path to bin in `PATH` variable explicitly i.e. `%PATH%;C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;`. Also, I included the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `PATH`, though it is not required for running `mvn -version`. Tried running in administrator mode too. No improvements here.

So, I ran the command for checking the path:

```
dir %M2_HOME%\bin\mvn*
```

and it gives the output:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

So, I explicitly echoed the three variables in command prompt but they seem to give the correct paths. Where is the problem? I tried re-downloading the zip files and extracted again and modified variables by changing the destination directories. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Program Files folder name probably contains spaces. Change ProgramFiles(x86) to Program Files (x86) or progra~2.

Comment: Initially it Didn't work with spaces, then I tried progra~2, it worked, I changed to spaces again, it didnt work again. So, I restarted my system, it works then. Thanks!! :)

Comment: If spaces are a problem you can usually enclose the complete path with quotes (") but for environment variables it is not required.